# VBA code to extract data from website by continuing number series of data

Tags: excel, vba

I desperately need your help to extract data from this webpage, here I have to enter number and than it reflect the information. I want a macro that can enter value in that field and than extract data in excel.

This is the website address
http://exportefiling.fbr.gov.pk/igm/IGMview1.aspx

I will put number value in IGM field and it will show data that I need in excel, after that I will add next number in IGM field that will reflect data and that needs to be copied on excel. I need this loop to be continued to a desired number e.g. starting number is 11105 and ending value is 11200. Please help I cannot attach screen shot here.

Comment: **First of all:** You need to come up with a more specific question. Right now, you are basically asking for someone who will write the code for you. That won't happen. **Second:** Automation like what you ask for, is browser based. You need to specify which browser you want to use.

Comment: Hi, I can use internet explorer or Chrome.

Comment: I requested this as I do not have any knowledge about VB codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (although it is doable without). I have never used it in VBA, but it appears to be available on [Github](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases). The other way is using the COM interface (only available in Internet Explorer), but that is kind of an old fashioned solution, compared to Selenium.

Comment: But seems its not workable. Anyone else wo can help me. Its urgent please.